# how to upload files to PHP server with use of Python?

Tags: php, python, file-upload

I was wondering is there any tutorial out there that can teach you how to push multiple files from desktop to a PHP based web server with use of Python application?

Edited

I am going to be writing this so I am wondering in general what would be the best method to push files from my desktop to web server. As read from some responses about FTP so I will look into that (no sFTP support sadly) so just old plain FTP, or my other option is to push the data and have PHP read the data thats being send to it pretty much like Action Script + Flash file unloader I made which pushes the files to the server and they are then fetched by PHP and it goes on from that point on.

Comment: Using what? FTP? SFTP? A PHP file that takes file uploads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you own the PHP server.

- Use FTP. See [here](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html) and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php).
- Make a file upload form with PHP, and use python to fill out the form. See [this](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) and [this](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php).
- (Usually a bad idea) Use PHP to write small server that listens for data and then writes it to a file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're referring to a application made in php running on some website in which case thats just normal HTTP stuff.
So just look at what name the file field has on the html form generated by that php script and then do a normal post. (urllib2 or whatever you use)